Show boundedness of set if optimization problem has a global solution
Show that a non-empty closed set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact iff for every $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the problem $\min c^Tx,x\in \Omega$ has a global solution.
For "$\Rightarrow$" I have: Since $\Omega$ is compact and $c^Tx$ is linear (hence continuous) the function attends its minimum and maximum in $\Omega$. Hence the minimization problem has a solution.
For "$\Leftarrow$" I let $x'$ be the global solution of the problem, then for every $x$ we have $c^Tx'\leq c^Tx$. Then for $c=\frac{x}{||x||}$ we have:
$$\frac{x^T}{||x||}x'\leq\frac{x^T}{||x||}x=\frac{||x||^2}{||x||}=||x||$$
This is where I'm stuck. According to my understanding a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded if for every $x$ in that subset $||x||\leq b$ for some $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Together with the assumpted that $\Omega$ is closed I'd have shown that it is compact.
EDIT: As I have researched, this problem should be equivalent to showing that if the feasible region for a linear program (LP) is unbounded then there exists no optimal solution, hence proof by contradiction. However, I couldn't find a proof to this statement.

If $\Omega$ is not bounded there is a sequence of nonzero vectors $x_i \in \Omega$ such that $||x_i||\rightarrow\infty$, so the sequence $\frac{x_i}{||x_i||}$ is in the compact set $S={x\in\mathbb{R}^n:||x||=1}$ and you can use Bolzano-Wierstrass to find a convergent subsequence that converges to some point $d\in S$, meaning $||d||=1$. Define $c=-d$.

For the "$\Leftarrow$" direction, your idea of normalization is on the right track. Below is a complete argument that uses this (with $y$ being a point of the form $x/\|x\|$).

By way of contradiction, suppose the set $\Omega$ is not bounded. This implies, for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a point $x^k \in \Omega$ such that $\|x^k\| \geq k$.
Define the sequence $\{y^k\}$ by
$$y^k = \frac{x^k}{\|x^k\|},\quad \mbox{for all}\ k\in\mathbb{N},$$
noting each division is well-defined since $\|x^k\|\geq k > 0$. Because $\|y^k\| = 1$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the sequence $\{y^k\}$ is bounded. Thus, by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, $\{y^k\}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{y^{n_k}\}$ with a limit $y$ that also satisfies $\|y\|=1$.
This implies there is an index $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ \begin{align*} 
& 1 \geq \|y-y^{n_k}\|^2 =\|y\|^2 - 2y^\top y^{n_k} + \|y^{n_k}\|^2
\quad\mbox{for all}\ k \geq N,
\end{align*}$$
and so
$$ -y^\top y^{n_k} \leq \frac{1 - \|y\|^2 - \|y^{n_k}\|^2}{2} = \frac{1-1-1}{2} = - \frac{1}{2},\quad\mbox{for all}\ k\geq N.$$
Letting $c = -y$ reveals
$$\begin{align*} 
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} c^\top x^{n_k}
& = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} c^\top y^{n_k} \|x^{n_k}\| \\
& = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}  - y^\top y^{n_k} \|x^{n_k}\| \\ 
& \leq \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} -\frac{\|x^{n_k}\|}{2} \\
& \leq \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}  -\frac{k}{2} \\
& = -\infty.
\end{align*} $$
Since the sequence $\{x^{n_k}\}$ is in $\Omega$, it follows that no global solution exists to the problem of minimizing $c^\top x$ over $x\in \Omega$, a contradiction. Therefore, the initial assumption was false and we conclude $\Omega$ is bounded.
